# Add better descriptions and E/R diagram to Data Explorer's schema

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

Schema should show descriptions and possible values for fields. Maybe it should even have some kind of entity-relationship diagram for the tables.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250439/158100

Answer (score 5):

I've added a subtle question mark icon next to the Database schema title in the compose query view:

[image: question mark icon next to Database schema title, left of sort and collapse/expand buttons]

Clicking the question mark brings you to [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677)

The changed Editor.cshtml can be found in [Pull Request 108](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/108). This is now deployed and live in rev 2020.12.13.80.

Answer (score 2):

I added hints on hover for the schema which helps stuff out, if anybody wants an ER diagram, if you can make a sexy one I can add a link to it below the schema, even make it show up in a light box