# Is there a Data Dictionary for the data.stackexchange tables?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, schema

Is there a data dictionary showing the relations between tables? If so, where can I find this?

I'd like to become more familiar with the schema :)

is [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer) the best/official post to look at for the information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really, although all of the relations follow a pretty self-evident naming pattern of `<[prefix?][table]Id>`. If you'd be interested in something a bit more visual, I'd suggest throwing an up vote in the direction of [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51964/add-better-descriptions-and-e-r-diagram-to-data-explorers-schema) and I'd be willing to take a look at it. Data Explorer is [open source](https://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/), so direct patches are also welcome*.

In the meantime, the post you've linked to is probably the best source of supplementary information for the schema, although it's a bit out of date. The schema in the side bar of the [query editor on Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) is generated from the actual table metadata, so it's ultimately the most authoritative source.

<sub>*The code might be transitioning to GitHub in the near future, which should hopefully make this easier</sub>

Comment: Thanks, Tim! Having only recently worked professionally with 'industrial sized' relational databases, I now appreciate how useful data dictionaries can be. Even a simple excel spreadsheet that gives a description of the field, and it's foreign/primary key description would be really helpful! ... Upvote has been given...maybe i'll try assembling something if I get a better understanding...maybe..

Comment: is there a more recent data dump than the September '11 version? I'm not sure how to get the database out of http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/browse/#hg%2FApp%2FStackExchange.DataExplorer

Comment: You can grab the August '12 data dump [from ClearBits](http://www.clearbits.net/torrents/2076-aug-2012).

Answer (score 1):

Found this pretty useful site... not sure how up-to-date it is though.

http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Understanding_the_StackOverflow_Database_Schema, there is also a SQL script on importing the data-dumps, [but as I found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143339/how-can-i-increase-xml-data-type-in-sql-server-2008), there is a 2GB limit to SQL Server importing XMLS, so i'm still out of luck on that front. Eitherway, it's a very helpful resource.