# Stack Exchange Table Structure

Tags: feature-request, support, review, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Add better descriptions and E/R diagram to Data Explorer’s schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51964/add-better-descriptions-and-e-r-diagram-to-data-explorers-schema)

I was messing around with the [**Stack Exchange Data Explorer**](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and it appears that not all the tables are present in the database schema.  Either that or I don't fully understand how the data is stored.  I was wanting to create some queries to gather statistics of the new review system.

What tables is the data stored in when a user does completes a review action in one of the six categories? If the tables are not available, can they be made available for writing queries against?

Also, is there a data diagram available somewhere to look at?

Comment: This data isn't in there... make this a feature request and I'll definitely upvote. The more data the better.

Comment: Looks like the dev team expects us (ordinary mortal users) to build such diagram based on [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53039/152859). (Sam no longer works for SE but I'm pretty sure what he said stands still)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, only the last question about the data diagram is talked about in the link you presented

Comment: As far as I could understand this is feature request for such diagram plus some related questions. The "core" is the feature request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, not all tables are present; the schema of the Data Explorer is a filtered view of a Stack Exchange site. For example, who voted is not available, for good reasons.

The new review queue data has simply not been added to the Data Explorer yet; only the votes themselves (close, reopen, etc) are available, you would have to write [elaborate queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/89716/questions-in-and-out-the-close-votes-review-queue-sample-from-9-11-2012) that can approximate the information.

It could be that those missing tables will be added in a future revision, but no plans to do so have been announced (that I can see).

There is no data diagram available, I don't think. However, the data explorer exposes [OData feeds](http://www.odata.org/) (example: [Atom OData feed for SO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom)), so perhaps you could try using a [OData consumer tool](http://www.odata.org/ecosystem#consumers) to create one?