# Link to the SEDE guide should open a new tab rather than changing the current URL (of the query composer)

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, data-explorer, tabs

The [compose query page](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) displays a [**?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) icon that directs us to the [schema documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede):

[image: Image of the SEDE compose query page, with the ? icon underlined for highlighting.]

Please make it so that the link opens up a new tab rather than changing the current URL without any prompt asking if the user wants to leave their unsaved query.

If a new tab is not possible, adding a prompt would also be an option.

Comment: Might want to make it a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/issues) - SEDE is an open-source initiative, after all

Comment: I introduced that question mark in the PR mentioned in this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353941  It is an anchor tag so adding `target="_blank"` should work

Comment: @rene Oh. Do you own the data explorer?

Comment: No, I don't own it but I did submit a couple of minor PRs to get things fixed.